# How does Transition properties in CSS work?

Tags: html, css

I am studying `transition` in CSS, I watched some tutorials on YouTube and I feel so confused about this.

A piece of code HTML

```html
        <ul class="navbar__menu">
            <li class="navbar__item">
                <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="home-page">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar__item">
                <a href="#about" class="navbar__links" id="about-page">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar__item">
                <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" id="services-page">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar__btn">
                <a href="#sign-up" class="button" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

and with two code snippets CSS

Code snippet 1

```css
.navbar__links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 125px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
  color: #9518fc;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

Code snippet 2

```css
.navbar__links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 125px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
  color: #9518fc;
}
```

Why the instructor insert `transition: all 0.3s ease;` into both two class. I tried both cases, but I don't see any difference.

So, anyone can explain to me, which one is right?

Comment: It is unnecessary in this case, because when `.navbar__links:hover` applies, the `transition` value has already been set via the rule with the `.navbar__links` selector, which applies regardless of the element's state. Specifying a _different_ transition for the `:hover` state can make sense, if you want a _different_ behavior between the user "entering" and "leaving" the element.

Comment: thanks. I don't really understand the last part, "entering", "leaving". what I can do to achieve that

Comment: I was simply referring to when the mouse cursor enters an element (which will then put that element into the `:hover` state) and leaving it again.

Comment: thanks for your assistance in helping me to understand that problem more clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you would "typically" want to set the `transition` property on the base style of the item; as in your first snippet (also copied below).

This is interesting because what you've found is that you can apply different transitions at different times.

Take the second snippet, which I've change so that the `:hover` transition takes `1.3s` instead. You'll notice that when hovering the transition is slow, but when un-hovering the transition if fast again, and this is what some developers use to make **asymmetric-transitions** for different actions/states of the UI.

Its worth noting that `all` is often considered "unfavourable" as it could lead to applying transitions to all sorts of unexpected properties, so it is often better practice to specify the `transition-property`, such as:

```css
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
```

Additionally, not "all" properties can be animated in this way, for example `display` cannot be animated (at least not at the time of writing, Nov 2023)

```css
.navbar__links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 125px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
  color: #9518fc;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar__menu">
  <li class="navbar__item">
    <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="home-page">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar__item">
    <a href="#about" class="navbar__links" id="about-page">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar__item">
    <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" id="services-page">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar__btn">
    <a href="#sign-up" class="button" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```css
.navbar__links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 125px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
  color: #9518fc;
  transition: all 1.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar__menu">
  <li class="navbar__item">
    <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="home-page">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar__item">
    <a href="#about" class="navbar__links" id="about-page">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar__item">
    <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" id="services-page">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar__btn">
    <a href="#sign-up" class="button" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT:

To summarise:

- It's all about the initial state of the user's interaction
- When you start to hover, the initial state is "not hovering"

  - The styling used is `.navbar__links` (which can also be expressed as `.navbar__links:not(:hover)`)
- When you stop hovering (i.e. leaving) the initial state is "hovering" so `.navbar__links:hover` is used

  - This is noticeable in the second snippet when you stop hovering on any of the links, the transition timing is now `1.3s` because it is using the style in `.navbar__links:hover`

Comment: thanks for your answer, maybe there are many things you said that I don't know yet, I only want to know effect on code snippets 1 and 2. Can you describe in detail for me

Comment: In the case of code snippet 1: when I add or remove `transition: all 0.3s ease;` into `.navbar__links:hover`, what is the difference?

Comment: Between snippet one and two (of your snippets) there is no difference and you don't need to add the `transition` property in the `:hover` CSS. But if you put a `transition` property in the `:hover` CSS it would allow you to add different CSS animations when you are hovering on the element. Your second snippet (with no `transition` property in the `:hover` CSS) would be the "better" way to control the animations as it's simpler to read and follow

Comment: Adding the `transition` to `.navbar__links:hover` means that: the animation `all 0.3s ease` would be used when the user is currently hovering on `.navbar__links`

Comment: I see, `transition` in `.navbar_links` is not for `hover` action, so what is that?

Comment: according to my understand, there are two state: `hovering` and `leaving`, if I only put one `transition: all 0.3s ease;`  into `navbar__links`, it work on both states. if I put `transition: all 0.3s ease;` into both classes, second transition will override `hovering` state, right?

Comment: Yes, it's all about the initial state of the interaction. When you start to hover, the initial state is "not hovering" (which is essentially `.navbar__links:not(:hover)`), so the transition in `.navbar__links` is used. When you stop hovering (i.e. `leaving`) the initial state is "hovering" so `.navbar__links:hover` is used.

Comment: Hmm, I'm starting to grasp it a little. So, could you summary and edit according to the discussion for me to accept the answer?

Comment: No worries, done